# Accessing a list of users through JBoss in a non-admin role?

Tags: jboss, jboss-portal

We would like to make a list of users available in a portlet similar to the admin version of the UsersPortlet, but for those that aren't admins. This list would be names only. Is there a way to do this through JBoss GA 4.2.2? We are currently developing on the Hypersonic DB, but I would hope there is a DB independent way to do this through JBoss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the [Identity Manager](http://docs.jboss.org/jbportal/v2.7.1/referenceGuide/html/identity.html) and its associated classes. Using the default configurations source code can be:

```
import org.jboss.portal.identity.UserModule;
import org.jboss.portal.identity.RoleModule;
import org.jboss.portal.identity.MembershipModule;
import org.jboss.portal.identity.UserProfileModule;

[...]

(UserModule)new InitialContext().lookup("java:portal/UserModule");
RoleModule rm = (RoleModule)new InitialContext().lookup("java:portal/RoleModule");
(MembershipModule)new InitialContext().lookup("java:portal/MembershipModule");
(UserProfileModule)new InitialContext().lookup("java:portal/UserProfileModule");

rm.findRoles()
```

A critical gotcha that got us is that for the InitialContext to be properly populated this must occur in a transaction. That means if you are using RichFaces this can't take place in the underlying beans.